# Multiple MySQL Table JOINs / id-to-value replacement / aliases

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, select, join

I have two tables which I want to create a selection from, such that the reference ids in the first table are replaced by the values in the second table. An optimized query for a huge database is preferred. The following illustrates my goal:

```
TABLE_KINGDOMS
==============
kid     kingdom      id_king      id_queen      id_prince      id_princess
--      -------      -------      --------      ---------      -----------
1       red          1            2             3              4
2       blue         5            6             7              8
...

TABLE_PLAYERS
=============
pid     username      points      gold
--      --------      ------      ----
1       Jack          34789       35667
2       Jill          2312        23887
3       Walt          8756        23112
4       Winnie        587         255
5       Eric          76521       34678
6       Alice         6799        7549
7       Ned           5565        9009
8       Rose          2312        3429
...

DESIRED_SELECTION (Replace id with username)
=================
kid     kingdom      king      queen      prince      princess
--      -------      ----      -----      ------      --------
1       red          Jack      Jill       Walt        Winnie
2       blue         Eric      Alice      Ned         Rose
...
```

I have tried the following, but it isn't working:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_kingdoms
LEFT JOIN table_users ON id_king = tu.id
LEFT JOIN table_users ON id_queen = tu.id
LEFT JOIN table_users ON id_prince = tu.id
LEFT JOIN table_users ON id_princess = tu.id
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have the `alias` definition in your actual query? In the example you provided here you are missing `table_users AS tu`. Also, it **really** seems that your database needs to be normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced you `LEFT JOINS` with `INNER`, as none of your IDs in table_kingdoms are nulls, put the `LEFT` back if the ids can be null, otherwise `INNER` is better.  Your query column and table names are different than what is in your structures so I wasn't sure which to use.  So if this doesn't get what you need, specify what you mean by *doesn't work* and we can address the specific issue.

```
SELECT K.kid,K.Kingdom, P.Username as King,PQ.Username as Queen,
PP.Username as Prince,PS.Username as Princess
FROM table_kingdoms K
INNER JOIN TABLE_PLAYERS PK ON K.id_king = PK.pid --replace TABLE_PLAYERS  with table_users depending on the actual table name
--LEFT JOIN table_users ON id_king = tu.id REPLACE WITH ABOVE
INNER JOIN TABLE_PLAYERS PQ ON K.id_queen = PQ.pid --replace TABLE_PLAYERS  with table_users depending on the actual table name
--LEFT JOIN table_users ON id_queen = tu.id  REPLACE WITH ABOVE
INNER JOIN TABLE_PLAYERS PP ON K.id_prince = PP.pid --replace TABLE_PLAYERS  with table_users depending on the actual table name
--LEFT JOIN table_users ON id_prince = tu.id  REPLACE WITH ABOVE
INNER JOIN TABLE_PLAYERS PS ON K.id_princess = PS.pid --replace TABLE_PLAYERS  with table_users depending on the actual table name
--LEFT JOIN table_users ON id_princess = tu.id  REPLACE WITH ABOVE
```

As far as your original query goes,it is pretty close.  The biggest thing is you are saying tu.id but never declared that as an alias AND you can't reuse the same alias  Then also, you have to define the columns the way you want them, but this is not an error.  Here is an edit for the things I mentioned above that are actual errors:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_kingdoms
LEFT JOIN table_users tu ON id_king = tu.id
LEFT JOIN table_users  tu2 ON id_queen = tu2.id
LEFT JOIN table_users tu3 ON id_prince = tu3.id
LEFT JOIN table_users  tu4 ON id_princess = tu4.id
```

And just as a note, I'd personally also alias table_kingdoms and here that is also including column display:

```
SELECT K.kid,K.Kingdom, tu.Username as King, tu2.Username as Queen,
tu3.Username as Prince,tu4.Username as Princess
FROM table_kingdoms k
LEFT JOIN table_users tu ON k.id_king = tu.id
LEFT JOIN table_users  tu2 ON k.id_queen = tu2.id
LEFT JOIN table_users tu3 ON k.id_prince = tu3.id
LEFT JOIN table_users  tu4 ON k.id_princess = tu4.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Just give different aliases to the joined tables.

```sql
SELECT k.kid, k.kingdom,
   uk.username AS king,
   uq.username AS queen,
   up.username AS prince
   ups.username AS princess
FROM table_kingdoms k
LEFT JOIN table_users uk ON k.id_king = uk.pid
LEFT JOIN table_users uq ON k.id_queen = uq.pid
LEFT JOIN table_users up ON k.id_prince = up.pid
LEFT JOIN table_users ups ON k.id_princess = ups.pid;
```

Also, `LEFT JOIN` can be omitted as I assume `id_...` fields cannot be `NULL`.