# JOIN 2 SQL table (1 field at table 1 replace more than 1 field at the other table)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Someone please help me.

I have 2 tables, My Database is MySQL

table1

```
user_id | username
------- | --------
1       | joni
2       | adam
3       | jerry
4       | Dino
```

table2

```
dokumen_id | create_by | update_by | last_access_by |
doc_001    | 2         | 1         | 2              |
doc_002    | 3         | 2         | 1              |
doc_003    | 1         | 1         | 4              |
```

I want to join 2 tables in one query and the result like this

```
dokumen_id | create_by | update_by | last_access_by |
doc_001    | adam      | joni      | adam           |
doc_002    | jerry     | adam      | joni           |
doc_003    | joni      | joni      | dino           |
```

how do i write the query?

many thanks for the help.

Comment: You could have helped yourself by googling, say, "stackoverflow.com replace ids by names join 2 sql table database".

Comment: thanks @philipxy but that question can't answer my question. i have more than 1 field ID at table 2.

Comment: Suggest you read more than one result link. Eg the *second* is [Multiple MySQL Table JOINs / id-to-value replacement / aliases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102669/multiple-mysql-table-joins-id-to-value-replacement-aliases).

Comment: Thanks @philipxy, that result exactly what i mean. sometimes i need quickly to get the answer, nextime i will try to search the result link before i post my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Join `table1` thrice

```
SELECT t2.dokumen_id,
       c.username AS create_by,
       u.username AS update_by,
       l.username AS last_access_by
FROM   table2 t2
       LEFT JOIN table1 c
              ON t2.create_by = c.user_id
       LEFT JOIN table1 u
              ON t2.update_by = u.user_id
       LEFT JOIN table1 l
              ON t2.last_access_by = l.user_id
```

Left Outer Join is used to return all the records from `table2`, a user might have present in `create_by` but not in `last_access_by` in that case Inner join will filter the records who is not present in `create_by`

Comment: @Prdp See. Told ya

Comment: i mean i got the query from @Prdp

Answer (score 2):

Join the `table1` three times with `table2`

```
select t1.dokumen_id,
  tc.username create_by,
  tu.username update_by,
  ta.username last_access_by
from table2 t1
left outer join table1 tc
  on tc.user_id = t1.create_by
left outer join table1 tu
  on tu.user_id = t1.update_by
left outer join table1 ta
  on ta.user_id = t1.last_access_by;
```

Comment: dup of my answer ;)

Comment: I had posted the whole thing when there was a `*` in your `select` :D

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.user_id=table2.last_access_by;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Join table1 thrice

```
SELECT t2.dokumen_id,
       c.username AS create_by,
       u.username AS update_by,
       l.username AS last_access_by
FROM   table2 t2
       LEFT JOIN table1 c
              ON t2.create_by = c.user_id
       LEFT JOIN table1 u
              ON t2.update_by = u.user_id
       LEFT JOIN table1 l
              ON t2.last_access_by = l.user_id
```